# Finding a vector direction that deviates approximately equally by e.g. 5 degree from all other vector directions in a set

Tags: python

I have a set of approximately 10,000 vectors max (random directions) in 3d space and I'm looking for a new direction v_dev (vector) which deviates from all other directions in the set by e.g. a minimum of 5 degrees. My naive initial try is the following, which has of course bad runtime complexity but succeeds for some cases.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np

numVecs = 10000
vecs = np.random.rand(numVecs, 3)
randVec = np.random.rand(1, 3)

notFound=True
foundVec=randVec
below=False

iter = 1
for vec in vecs:
    angle = np.rad2deg(np.arccos(np.vdot(vec, foundVec)/(np.linalg.norm(vec) * np.linalg.norm(foundVec))))
    print("angle: %f\n" % angle)

while notFound:
  for vec in vecs:
    angle = np.rad2deg(np.arccos(np.vdot(vec, randVec)/(np.linalg.norm(vec) * np.linalg.norm(randVec))))
    if angle < 5:
      below=True

  if below:
    randVec = np.random.rand(1, 3)
  else:
    notFound=False

  print("iteration no. %i" % iter)
  iter = iter + 1
```

Any hints how to approach this problem (language agnostic) would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the vectors in a spherical coordinate system (u,w,r), where r is always 1 because vector length doesn't matter here. Any vector can be expressed as (u,w) and the "deadzone" around each vector x, in which the target vector t cannot fall, can be expressed as `dist((u_x, w_x, 1), (u_x-u_t, w_x-w_t, 1)) < 5°`. However calculating this distance can be a bit tricky, so converting back into cartesian coordinates might be easier. These deadzones are circular on the spherical shell around the origin and you're looking for a t that doesn't hit any on them.

For any fixed u_t you can iterate over all x and using the distance function can find the start and end point of a range of w_t, that are blocked because they fall into the deadzone of the vector x. The union of all 10000 ranges build the possible values of w_t for that given u_t. The same can be done for any fixed w_t, looking for a u_t.

Now comes the part that I'm not entirely sure of: Given that you have two unknows u_t and w_t and 20000 knowns, the system is just a tad overdetermined and if there's a solution, it should be possible to find it.

My suggestion: Set u_t fixed to a random value and check which w_t are possible. If you find a non-empty range, great, you're done. If all w_t are blocked, select a different u_t and try again. Now, selecting u_t at random will work eventually, yet a smarter iteration should be possible. Maybe `u_t(n) = u_t(n-1)*phi % 360°`, where phi is the golden ratio. That way the u_t never repeat and will cover the whole space with finer and finer granularity instead of starting from one end and going slowly to the other.

Edit: You might also have more luck on the mathematics stackexchange since this isn't so much a code question as it is a mathematics question. For example I'm not sure what I wrote is all that rigorous, so I don't even know it works.

Comment: One comment: There is no guarantee one would find such a direction which will deviate by e.g. 5 degree minimum at least, correct? It might be that one has to lower the minimum degree threshold to find a direction?

Comment: Correct, there is no guarrantee. Now, I'd wager there is a number of vector for which there always will be solution since they cannot over the whole spherical shell, but from a gut feeling 10000 should certainly be enough to over it in 5° circles.

Comment: That makes sense. Why are you using the golden ratio in your iteration scheme?

Comment: You can use a fixed iteration step, but this has two disadvantages: It repeats eventually and it iterates over the whole space in a quasi-continuous manner, meaning that if the "holes" happen to be on the other end, it will take a while to get there. Golden ratio sequences (e.g as described in Golden Ratio Sequences for Low-Discrepancy Sampling by Scretter et al) avoid these two disadvantages.

Comment: Etienne Ott: Thanks, I'll check the publication.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be two build a 2d manifold (area on the sphere) of forbidden areas. You start by adding a point, then, the forbidden area is a circle on the sphere surface.

While true, pick a point on the boundary of the area. If this is not close (within 5 degrees) to any other vector, then, you're done, return it. If not, you just found a new circle of forbidden area. Add it to your manifold of forbidden area. You'll need to chop the circle in line or arc segments and build the boundary as a list.

If the set of vector has no solution, you boundary will collapse to an empty point. Then you return failure.

It's not the easiest approach, and you'll have to deal with the boundaries of a complex shape over a sphere. But it's guaranteed to work and should have reasonable complexity.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey. Just to understand this correctly: I start with a random initial point and add it to the surface. Around this point, e.g. 5 degrees, this will be a "forbidden zone" on the sphere surface. Correct?

Comment: Yep. As a list of arcs of line segment. But managing the list might get a bit hairy. Maybe something like a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_connected_edge_list but on the surface of a sphere instead of on a plane.

Comment: And holes may form. If the first, say, 8 vectors you find form an octogon on the sphere, then you have both an area in their middle and on the outside.

Comment: Will the holes be a problem per se?

Comment: So the boundary needs to be explicitly stored as a list of arcs of line segments? You wrote pick a point on the boundary, how would I choose the next point?